# aquarium polluted water differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An aquarium contains 10 gallons of polluted water.A filter is attached to this aquarium which drains off the polluted water at the rate of 5 gallons per hour.and replaces it at the same rate by pure water.How long does it take to reduce the pollution to half of its initial level?
ans is 2log2.
I did not understand 2nd line.If i take x gallon polluted water at any time t  then dx/dt= -5
which is not correct as answer contains log term means some proportionality with x is there.
Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misleading part is the statement that you are removing "polluted water".  The rate of removing this water is clearly constant. **But** your goal is to remove the **pollutant**, the stuff in the water, and its concentration goes down from the first moment.

Assume that at some time $t$ the tank contains $y$ pollutant. It could be grams of salt, ounces of ammonia or whatever. As you pump out a little of this polluted water in a short time $dt$, the amount of $y$ changes. Since the $y$ of pollutant is spread out over the whole 10 gallons, the concentration is $\frac{y}{10}$.  You are removing 5 gallons of this polluted water per hour, so in a time $dt$ you remove a volume $5\times dt$.  So the change in the amount of y, $dy$, is given by$$dy=-\frac{y}{10}\times 5 \times dt $$and the solution to this equations proceeds as above.

Comment: very well explained.thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think they mean

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{y}{2}$$

That is, the rate at which the filter drains and replaces water is $1/2$ the amount of water in the aquarium.  Then

$$y(t) = y(0) \, e^{-t/2}$$

To find the time it takes to drain and replace $1/2$ the water in the aquarium, take logs of both sides:

$$1/2 = e^{-t/2} \implies t = 2 \log{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

The differential equation is not $x'(t)=-5$, because the rate at which the pollution leaves is proportional to the pollution in the tank. If you assume the water is perfectly mixed, taking $5$ gallons out will take half of the remaining pollution out (since the tank is $10$ gallons). For example, if there are $3$ gallons of pollution left, and the water is perfectly mixed, then taking out $5$ gallons removes $1.5$ gallons of pollution and $3.5$ gallons of pure water.

You can carry this observation over to the infinitesimal level: the rate at which the pollution leaves the tank is proportional to half the pollution in the tank. In symbols:

$$x'(t)=-\frac{1}{2}x(t).$$

Solving this, we get $$x(t)=ce^{-t/2}$$

for some constant $c$, which we determine by using the information that $x(0)=10$.

Solving, we find $c=10$, so $$x(t)=10e^{-t/2}.$$

We want half of the pollution to remain, or $5$ gallons. We solve for $t$ in

$$5=10e^{-t/2}\Rightarrow 1/2=e^{-t/2}.$$

Taking logarithms, we find $t=2\log 2$.